# Handling and logging ORA-06512 error code

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-logging

I have just created an error_log table to log any errors that a procedure/package may run into. the error log table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE APMS.ERROR_LOG
(
ORA_ERR_TMSP     TIMESTAMP(6)                 NOT NULL,
ORA_ERR_NUMBER   NUMBER(5)                    NOT NULL,
ORA_ERR_MSG      VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)           NOT NULL,
ORA_ERR_TXT      VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)           NOT NULL,
ORA_ERROR_OPTYP  CHAR(1 CHAR)                 NOT NULL,
PROGRAM_NAME     VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)            NOT NULL,
ORA_IN_OUT       VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)           NOT NULL
)
```

I created a mock table an purposely induced the ORA-06512 error by inserting a character string in a timestamp field using a procedure. here is the procedure which inserts dummy data into my mock table with the purpose of inducing an error and logging it into my error_log table.

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure as 

begin 
  insert into mockdata values ('data1','mockname','mockcity');
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    insert into error_log 
    values   
    (ora_err_tmsp,ora_err_number,ora_err_msg,ora_err_txt,ora_err_optyp,program_name,ora_in_out);
    values
    (current_timestamp,sqlcode,'sqlerrm', 'detailed information','i','test_procedure','i');
    commit;
end;
/
```

when I attempt to run/compile it I get the following error.

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (9: 1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUES" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
   pragma raise return select update when while with
   <an
```

I am a complete beginner at pl/sql so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra `values` word in the second insert. After `error_log` word exactly

Comment: and extra semicolon after the column list Before valid VALUES keyword

Comment: And you would never, ever, ever in real life have a `when others` clause that did not include a `raise`, right?  (or that raised a new custom exception)?

Comment: In the Real World (ain't never been there - they tell me it's nice :-) you might want do the logging in a procedure with PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION so that you could commit your log messages without affecting the main transaction. Oh - and always, Always, ALWAYS use a field list with an INSERT statement. Thou Shalt Not Count Upon Thy Table Layout Remaining Stable Unto Eternity - Don't Ask Me How I Know. Best of luck.

Comment: another issue: ...(current_timestamp,sqlcode,'sqlerrm', <<< here you are inserting the word 'sqlerrm'. no apices needed if you want to insert the value of sqlerrm

Comment: Thank you so much, This community has been great in the learning process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting into your code: if you are planning to write that kind of logging in every procedure you write, maybe you should simply avoid doing it and keep at reach of your hand this trigger and enable it just when you need it: this trigger might be handy in a testing environment or if you are in deep trouble and you need to collect all possible error that happen in a given time:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_all_errors  AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE
     declare
        procedure log_error is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
        begin                  
            INSERT INTO error_log
            VALUES (SYSDATE, SYS.LOGIN_USER, SYS.INSTANCE_NUM, SYS.DATABASE_NAME, DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
            commit;
        end;

     BEGIN
         log_error;
     END log_all_errors ;
```

this trigger will log ALL errors that will happen in your system. it is not a good idea to keep it enabled permanently: you can use it for doing some troubleshooting in emergency and you might want adjust its code to log only some kind of errors, but it is a starting point.
  if you do some research you will discover that you can even log the SQL text of the statement that caused the error.
  keep in mind that there are some errors that are not catched by this trigger (i am referring to NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS errors): there is simply too much code that normally uses these exceptions during its normal lifetime, so the guys at oracle decided not to trap these errors.

Now let's get back to your code: your approach, as other have pointed out, is not neutral to the normal execution of the program:

1. you are logging the error, right, but you are hiding the error to the program calling your procedure. It is not a good idea: the calling program surely would like to know that something wrong has happened and it would like to issue a "rollback" in order to cancel all previous work, instead of continuing like nothing wrong did happen.
2. Not only you are hiding the error, but you are also issuing a commit whenever an error happens: this is most likely the opposite of what your calling program would do in case of an error: surely the caller would issue a rollback. Instead you are making permanent all the partial work done until the error happened.
3. as a side note: the above problem of the unwanted commit even when no errors happen within your procedure: you are committing also when no errors are raised. this means that if the calling program enconuters some problems *after* having called your procedure, it won't be able to rollback anything it did before calling your code.

   It generally is a bad practice to commit or rollback inside a procedure, unless you are **more than sure** that such procedure will never be called as part of a bigger transaction (for example: it is ok to commit if your procedure is the main body of a database job)

So: how can you write an error log without interfering with the calling program? you do it by writing the log in a dedicted autonomous transaction" procedure:  whatever you do in procedure marked as "authonomous transaction" runs in its own separate transaction: you commit or rollback **only** what happens inside it.

*(As you can see, I used an autonomous transaction also in the above trigger)*

your code would be more "kind", to the calling program,  if written this way:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_procedure AS

        procedure write_error_log (errcode number, errstr varchar2) is
        pragma autonomous_transaction; 
        -- whatever we do in this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
        begin                         
              INSERT INTO error_log
                   (ora_err_tmsp,
                          ora_err_number,
                          ora_err_msg,
                          ora_err_txt,
                          ora_err_optyp,
                          program_name,
                          ora_in_out)
              values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                      errcode,
                      errstr,
                      'detailed information',
                      'i',
                      'test_procedure',
                      'i');
              COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
        end write_error_log;

     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mockdata
            VALUES ('data1', 'mockname', 'mockcity');
        --here you were committing: you'd better not do it:
        --  you are making impossible for the calling program to roll back 
        -- COMMIT; 
      exception when others then             
        write_error_log(sqlcode,sqlerrm);
        raise; -- you should NOT hide the exception to the caller program, so you'd better re-raise it!
     END test_procedure;
```

Comment: This was helpful and after playing with the code you provided I keep running into an error regarding " a raise statement with no exception name must be inside exception handler".

Comment: it is a typo: i accidentally deleted the "exceptions when others then" line.. I am fixing it now

Comment: Thank you so much, your code helped and the comments really helped me actually understand what I was doing. Also, your explanation was awesome. Thank you for your help! PL/SQL is pretty difficult

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_procedure
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mockdata
       VALUES ('data1', 'mockname', 'mockcity');

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      INSERT INTO error_log
           (ora_err_tmsp,
                  ora_err_number,
                  ora_err_msg,
                  ora_err_txt,
                  ora_err_optyp,
                  program_name,
                  ora_in_out)
      values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              SQLCODE,
              sqlerrm,
              'detailed information',
              'i',
              'test_procedure',
              'i');
      COMMIT;
END;
/
```